# rails error in post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to make a messenger app what did I did wrong
I get and  error that said No route matches [POST] "/message/new"

/message_controller.rb

```
class MessageController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @message=Message.new
  end

  def create
    @message=Message.new(:name,:email,:body)
    if @message.save
      redirect_to "message/view_all"
    end
  end

  def view_all
  end
end
```

app/views/message/new.html.erb

```
<%=form_for :message do |f|%>
  <h3>name</h3>
  <%=f.text_field :name %><br>
  <%=f.text_field :email %><br>
  <%=f.text_area :body %>
  <%=f.submit%>
<%end%>
```

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'message/new'
  post "message/create"=>"message#create"
  get 'message/view_all'
end
```

solution
in the controller:

```
def create
   @message=Message.new(params.require(:message).permit(:name,:email,:body))
   if @message.save
      redirect_to "/message/view_all"
   end
  end
```

in the views

```
<%=form_for @message, url:{action: "create"} do |f|%>
<h3>name</h3>
<%=f.text_field :name %><br>
<%=f.text_field :email %><br>
<%=f.text_area :body %>
<%=f.submit%>
<%end%>
```

in the routes

```
post "message/create"=>"message#create"
```

sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 1):

See in your routes, you only have `get 'message/new'`, you should replace your routes by:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :messages
  get 'message/view_all', to: "messages#view_all"
end
```

Also, in your form, replace `:message` by `@message`